# get website followers using sql

Tags: php, sql

I have got 3 tables :

**users**

> id
>   username

**images**

> id
>     user_id
>   image

**user_follow**

> id
>   user_id
>   follow_id

I am trying to get all users followers (friends) with their "username" from table users and "images" from table "images"

my query is :

```
"SELECT
u.username,
i.image
FROM users u, user_follow f, images i
WHERE f.user_id = 3 AND f.follow_id = u.id AND f.follow_id = i.user_id";
```

This query return followers only if they have image, if don't then return nothing.
I try to do query to return all followers and if is image with such (images.user_id = user_follow.follow_id) then return image if users do not have image in images table then return empty array

is it possible to get

```
[0] => Array
(
    [username] => 6666
    [image] => 
)
[1] => Array
(
    [username] => 3333
    [image] => my.jpg
)
[2] => Array
(
    [username] => 2222
    [image] =>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need to employ a **left outer join** to handle the 'even if image is null' condition.  Something like the following should help:

```
SELECT
    u.username
  , i.image
FROM
  users u
  -- normal join of users and user_follow
  INNER JOIN user_follow f on (u.id = f.follow_id)
  -- include images if they exist, null otherwise
  LEFT OUTER JOIN images i on (f.follow_id = i.user_id)
WHERE
  f.user_id = 3
;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all user with image or not with LEFT JOIN users and images tables like 
try below code,

```
select * from users u
  left outer join images i on u.id = i.user_id 
  left join user_follow f on f.follow_id = u.id
where  f.userid = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Although im not 100% sure i understand exactly what you want, the way i understand what you want is a [left join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

Have you tried something like:

```
SELECT u.username, i.image
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN images i
ON u.id= i.user_id
```